# Convert GET into POST

Tags: php, post, get

```
<?php  
    $amount= "10" ;

    if (!isset($_GET["action"]))
    {
    }
    elseif ($_GET["action"] == "write") // etc.
    {
        header('location: succes.php');
        $data = '' . PHP_EOL;
        $file = fopen('plugins/comments/comments/comments.txt', 'a');

        $message = str_replace("\r", '', $message);
        $message = str_replace("\n", '{{', $_GET['message']);
        fwrite($file, $_GET['name'] . '||' . date('d-m-Y') . '||' . 
            $message . $data);

        fclose($file);        
    }

    $start = (isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : 0);
    $gastenboek = Array();
    $gastenboek = file('plugins/comments/comments/comments.txt');
?>

<fieldset class="comments">
    <legend class="pm">Reacties</legend>
    <div style="float:right;">Aantal reacties:
        <b>
            <?php echo min($start+$amount,sizeof($gastenboek)); ?>
        </b>
    </div>

    <TABLE class="comments" width="100%">
        <?PHP
            $gastenboek=array_reverse($gastenboek);
            for ($i = $start; $i < $start+$amount && $i < sizeof($gastenboek); $i++)
            {
                list($name, $date, $message) = explode('||', $gastenboek[$i]);
                $message=str_replace('{{',"\n",$message);
                echo '
                    <TR>
                        <TD class="comments">
                            <div style="float:left;">
                                <B>'.$name.'</B>
                            </div>
                            <div style="float:right;">
                                (<i>'.$date.'</i>)
                            </div><br>
                            <p>' . str_replace("\n", '<BR>', htmlspecialchars($message)) . 
                            '</p> 
                        </TD>
                    </TR>'."\n";
            }
        ?>
    </TABLE>
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset class="pm">
    <legend class="pm">Plaats een reactie</legend>
    <FORM action="index.php" method="GET" onSubmit="return validate(this);"
        name="comments" id="comments">

        <INPUT type="hidden" name="action" value="write">

        <p class="pm">Naam: </p> 
        <INPUT type="text" name="name" size="30" style="width:300px;" required><br>

        <p class="pm2">Reactie: </p> 
        <TEXTAREA class="message" name="message" id="message" cols="46" rows="5" required>
        </TEXTAREA>
        <br>

        <INPUT type="submit" value="Reactie toevoegen">
    </FORM>
</fieldset>
```

I was wondering if this script could be converted into a using POST instead of a GET.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `method="post"` and $_POST instead of $_GET...

Comment: just two things: all `$_GET` to `$_POST` and form `method='POST'`

Comment: Or use $_REQUEST which can handle both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the form method from `method="get"` to `method="post"`.
Then you have to change the `$_GET` to `$_POST`.